# Codeigniter Database Error: Column doesnt exist

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've followed a few tutorials online on learning the CodeIgniter framework. I've tried to make a login and register function and everything should be working correctly however instead it shoots me back this error after I submit the register form.

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: `1054`
>
> Unknown column 'user_name' in 'field list'
>
> INSERT INTO 'users' ('user_name', 'user_password_hash', 'user_email') VALUES ('Test2', '$2a$08$cAkWVsvkaXvaumfcxW0gAOx2mBZMhIXxDpTQpHkOVme8l.1r9mok2', '1111')
>
> /www/application/models/user_model.php
>
> Line Number: 41

On line 41 of `User_model.php` is `$this->db->insert('users');`

```
public function add_user()
{
    $passunhash = $this->input->post('password');
    $passhash = $this->bcrypt->hash_password($passunhash);
    $uname = $this->input->post('user_name');
    $opin = $this->input->post('pin');

    $this->db->set('user_name', $uname);
    $this->db->set('user_password_hash', $passhash);
    $this->db->set('user_email', $opin);
    $this->db->insert('users');
}
```

The `database.php` config file has been edited to include the correct database name.

I cannot figure out why it would be giving me this database error. The column **does** exist. Could it be an issue with CodeIgniter?

Comment: how is your table structure? is there such a column?

Comment: It's showing you the exact SQL it's running. You can confirm if the column exists simply by opening up the MySQL CLI and running `SHOW COLUMNS FROM yourDB.users;`

Comment: You need to quote strings, else it thinks you are referring to column names.

Comment: @ZackTanner Thanks! It was PHPMYADMIN that was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

As zack tanner mentioned in the comments running `SHOW COLUMNS FROM yourDB.users;` from a mysql command line returns with all of the columns that the mysql client can read.

My PHPMYADMIN was getting old data and so running from command line displayed the realtime info. I was able to finish the rest of the commands through the command line in order to re structure the DB

Answer (score 0):

This may not solve your problem but when inserting user you can use a data array(); and not have multiple db->set()

```
public function add_user() {

$passunhash = $this->input->post('password');
$passhash = $this->bcrypt->hash_password($passunhash);

$data = array(
    'user_name' => $this->input->post('user_name'),
    'user_password_hash' => $passhash,
    'user_email' => $this->input->post('pin')
);

$this->db->set($data);
$this->db->insert($this->db->dbprefix . 'users');
}
```